# Look for a data structure to match words by letters

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given a list of lowercase radom words, each word with same length, and many patterns each with some letters at some positions are specified while other letters are unknown, find out all words that matches each pattern.

For example, words list is:

```
["ixlwnb","ivknmt","vvqnbl","qvhntl"]
```

And patterns are:

```
i-----
-v---l
-v-n-l
```

With a naive algorithm, one can do an O(NL) travel for each pattern, where N is the words count and L is the word length.

But since there may be a lot of patterns travel on the same words list, is there any good data structure to preprocess and store the words list, then give a sufficient matching for all patterns?

Answer (score 3):

One simple idea is to use an inverted index. First, number your words -- you'll refer to them using these indices rather than the words themselves for speed and space efficiency. Probably the index fits in a 32-bit int.

Now your inverted index: for each letter in each position, construct a sorted list of IDs for words that have that letter in that location.

To do your search, you take the lists of IDs for each of the letters in the positions you're given, and take the intersection of the lists, using a an algorithm like the  "merge" in merge-sort. All IDs in the intersection match the input.

Alternatively, if your words are short enough (12 characters or fewer), you could compress them into 64 bit words (using 5 bits per letter, with letters 1-26). Construct a bit-mask with binary `11111` in places where you have a letter, and `00000` in places where you have a blank. And a bit-test from your input with the 5-bit code for each letter in each place, using `00000` where you have blanks. For example, if your input is `a-c` then your bitmask will be binary `111110000011111` and your bittest binary `000010000000011`. Go through your word-list, take this bitwise `and` of each word with the bit-mask and test to see if it's equal to the bit-test value. This is cache friendly and the inner loop is tight, so may be competitive with algorithms that look like they should be faster on paper.

Comment: Nice solution, the merge on sorted list of IDs idea and compress words to bit test idea are awesome.

Answer (score 1):

I'll preface this with it's more of a comment and less of an answer (I don't have enough reputation to comment though). I can't think of any data structure that will satisfy the requirements of of the box. It was interesting to think about, and figured I'd share one potential solution that popped into my head.

I keyed in on the "same length" part, and figured I could come up with something based on that.

In theory we could have N(N being the length) maps of char -> set.
When strings are added, it goes through each character and adds the string to the corresponding set. psuedocode:

```
firstCharMap[s[0]].insert(s);
secondCharMap[s[1]].insert(s);
thirdCharMap[s[2]].insert(s);
fourthCharMap[s[3]].insert(s);
fifthCharMap[s[4]].insert(s);
sixthCharMap[s[5]].insert(s);
```

Then to determine which strings match the pattern, we take just do an intersection of the sets ex: "-v-n-l" would be:
intersection of sets: secondCharMap[v], fourthCharMap[n], sixthCharMap[l]

One edge case that jumps out is if I wanted to just get all of the strings, so if that's a requirement--we may also need an additional set of all of the strings.

This solution feels clunky, but I think it could work. Depending on the language, number of strings, etc--I wouldn't be surprised if it performed worse than just iterating over all strings and checking a predicate.

Comment: Still wonder if there is any improvement to the intersection part. I ever try to apply segment tree data structure but fail to work that out.

Comment: Yeah my first thought was there has to be a way to do it with trees. I wonder if you could store all of the strings in a tree with each level of the tree having nodes for each character. Then finding all strings would be writing a visitor based on your query. "-v-n-l" would: visit all nodes at the first level, visit only the v node on the second teir, visit all on the third, etc. I'm not sure how well it would work, I can't remember the last time I actually found a need to write my own tree vs using an stl container.

Comment: @JosephDing If you want matches in one shot, store all possible subsequences in a map if string lengths are small.